# is chaining exceptions valid

Tags: java, exception

During testing of a class I discovered that my class constructor could take an "illegal argument". The constructor was expecting a URI. Obviously if there is nothing suggesting that the passed argument is a URI, then it throws out an `IllegalArgumentException`.

My constructor originally tested the passed argument to see if it was a valid URI (by creating a file from it).
I then modified this to try the file creation and catch the `IllegalArgumentException`. In the body of my `catch` block I simply do:

```java
throw new URISyntaxException(passedArgument, message)
```

Is this a valid method for catching the possible exceptions that may be thrown, or should I be doing it some other way?

Also, as I found this issue while testing, am I justified in simply modifying the code to throw the exception I expect (and which is a more obvious error to present to the user, and put into the log)?

**Edit 1:** In response to comments, here is an example of my code:

```java
public myClass (String fileName) throws URISyntaxException {
    try {
        fileToRead = new File(fileName);

        if ( !fileToRead.canRead() ) { //confirm we can read the passed file
            // if not, throw a URI error
            throw new URISyntaxException(fileName, 'bad filename passed, please check path and try again');
        }
    } catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
        throw new URISyntaxException(fileName, 'bad filename passed, please check path and try again');
    }
}
```

In essence my question is, is it valid to throw a URI exception inside the `catch` block of the `IllegalArgumentException`?  Is this a valid practice, or could I do this better?

Comment: Is your question "Is there a way to catch all possible exceptions in Java?"

Comment: Please show us your code, and tell us what it is supposed to do. The explanation of what your code does is not clear, at least to me.

Comment: We need to know if your constructor had a `throw new IllegalArgumentException()` in its body AND a `catch` clause that threw something else.  Or if you have a "helper" method that throws the `IllegalArgumentException`. Or ....

Comment: Your constructor doesn't deal with URIs. Why make it throw an URIException? And why do you catch IllegalArgumentException? What in the constructor body could ever throw such an exception? Your constructor should just throw an IllegalArgumentException or an IOException. And it should not have any try/catch block.

Comment: @JBNizet I throw the URI as I convert the string into a FILE, I take a string as my argument so as I can throw my URI exception with a customised message, this was if I create this object I don't need to try catch around my code I can simply throw a URIException from my calling code, and my class documents the exceptions as being thrown so anyone else using can do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing isn't really [exception chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_chaining), unless you're actually wrapping the exception you caught inside that one you're throwing.  Instead, you're simply detecting the violation of a precondition by attempting an operation which you know will throw a certain exception if the precondition is violated, and then reporting the violation by throwing another exception.

The only potential problem I see with that is whether you *really* know for sure that the operation you're attempting will only throw the exception you're catching in that particular situation.  If there might be more than one reason why this operation could throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, but you're assuming that the cause will always be a specific one, then the exception you throw to report the issue might end up being misleading (e.g. reporting a valid URI as invalid, just because some *other* argument was invalid).

Basically, whenever you're catching a generic exception and throwing a more specific one instead, there's a risk that you might be mistaken about the cause of the generic exception.  But if you're *sure* that no such risk exists — for example, if the code you're calling clearly documents which exceptions it may throw under what conditions — then it should be fine.

---

**Edit** after actual code was added to the question:

Mostly unrelated to the general principles discussed above, I see several specific issues with your code.

1. First, if the `File` class your code uses is indeed [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), and you're passing the filename to the constructor as a `String` rather than as a `URI` object, then [the constructor you're calling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) isn't documented to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in any case, so trying to catch one is pointless.  The only `File` constructor that throws those is [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29).
2. Second, the fact that [`File.canRead()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29) returns false doesn't necessarily mean that the filename is invalid — it might be perfectly valid, and the file might even exist, but your program might not have the necessary permissions to read it.
3. Finally, as others have pointed out, I'm not sure what the "`URIException`" you're throwing actually is, unless it's a custom class you've written (there is a [`javax.print.URIException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/URIException.html), but that's an interface, not a class; the only other one I could find is [this one](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/URIException.html) from the Apache HTTP Client), but the name, at least, seems completely inappropriate for an exception which you're using to report an invalid (or unreadable) *file name*.  You really should use some other exception for that.

Comment: Ilmar in response to your questions, Yes I should be using java.io.file. Indeed my constructor only threw a URIException, but during testing I hit an IllegalArgumentException (which would fit with the link you posted. I use File.CanRead() in this instance as a blunt instrument to test the file is 'readable' I don't expect to have permission problems, but in hindsight I will adjust my error message appropriately. Sorry you are of course correct, its not a URIException I'm using, its a URISyntaxException from java.net.URI, I'll modify my code snippet accordingly. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's both valid and a best practice, but you should be throwing a custom exception or an IllegalArgumentException saying the constructor parameter is wrong, not a UriException